# ViewChild setter not detecting template ref inside ng-bootstrap modal

Tags: angular, typescript

Just like facebook when you want to change you profile picture you click the change button then a modal will appears, after that you can upload a new image or edit the old image.
I am using ng-bootstrap modal and ng2-img-cropper, when you click the edit profile picture button a modal will open using a template ref.
Inside that template ref there is another template ref "#cropper" pointing the image cropper component.

image cropper module has a built in function "setImage" to set the image of the cropper.
Before opening the modal i know the cropper ref will be undefined because the modal is not printed in the body yet.
Now when i search for this case i found a way to get that cropper element after the modal opens using the view child setter so this way the view child will retry to set the cropper when that template is available in the view.

this is my typescript code:

```js
  @ViewChild('cropper') set cropper(cropper:ImageCropperComponent) {
      //cropper.setImage(this.ImageHtmlElement);
      console.log(cropper);// prints : undefined
  }
```

And this is my HTML template:

```html
<template #profilpicmodal let-c="close" let-d="dismiss" ngbModalContainer>
 <div class="profile-cover-modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <div class="close-form ml-auto">
    <button type="button" class="close ml-auto" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
   </div>
   <span class="info your-photo-tab">
   <p>DID YOU KNOW?</p>
   <p>You can also add images from your phone</p>
  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-tabs">
   <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="upload" (click)="PhotoModalTab = 'upload'"><a class="btn btn-transparent" [ngClass]="{'active':PhotoModalTab == 'upload'}">Upload</a></li>
    <li class="your-photos" (click)="PhotoModalTab = 'filemanager'"><a class="btn btn-transparent" [ngClass]="{'active':PhotoModalTab == 'filemanager'}">Your Photos</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
   <div [hidden]="PhotoModalTab != 'upload'" ng2FileDrop class="upload-tab" (ng2FileDropFileAccepted)="dragFileAccepted($event,cropper)">
    <!--<img *ngIf="!ProfilePicData.original" src="./assets/images/Drag_Drop.png" alt="">-->
    <img-cropper #cropper [image]="ProfilePicData" [settings]="ProfilecropperSettings"></img-cropper><br>

    <div *ngIf="!ProfilePicData.original">
     <p class="drag-photo">Drag a Photo Here</p>
     <p class="drag-or">or</p>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-load-more" (click)="fileinput.click()">
    Upload
    <input #fileinput type="file" (change)="fileChangeListener($event.target.files[0],cropper)" id="upload" style="display:none;" />
   </a>
    <p class="drag-or mt-4 mb-0">For best results image should be at minimum 300px in height or width.</p>
   </div>
   <app-file-browser *ngIf="PhotoModalTab == 'filemanager'" (emitter)="SelectFileAndSave(closebtn,$event)"></app-file-browser>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
   <div class="buttons-section">
    <button #closebtn type="button" class="btn btn-load-more" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-load-more" *ngIf="PhotoModalTab == 'upload'" (click)="SaveImage(closebtn,ProfilePicData,'profile')">Save</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

At this point i got a very strange case that every time i try to log the cropper inside the view child setter i always got undefined and the application crash because the cropper has no function called setImage.
The application actually detecting the element as it is fire the setter again and prints the console.log at the browser console when i re open the modal but i don't know why the cropper is undefined

i tried also the ViewChidren ,sadly no luck.

Sorry for bad English

Comment: did u try to put 'cropper.setImage(this.ImageHtmlElement);' inside setTimeout function? like setTimeout(()=>{cropper.setImage(this.ImageHtmlElement);},0);

Comment: Try reproducing this in a plunker (you can fork one from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) - otherwise it is super hard / impossible to help properly...

Comment: Yes i try also the settimeout and didn't help,
this is a plunker and also i have same problem but in my pc the setter fires after opening the modal not when closing it
any way still undefined
[http://plnkr.co/edit/BakkAE1a71dWoqCsvrTN](http://plnkr.co/edit/BakkAE1a71dWoqCsvrTN)

Comment: Did you solved this? I have the same problem.

Comment: not yet sadly. but i didn't try it after upgrading to angular 4. i will test it this week and let you know.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Nope, nothing new. 
i changed the flow of my application because of it :\